# Showing that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$

Tags: power-series

I want to show the "simple" relation:

$$\sin' x=\cos x$$

by using power series. I know that:

$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Differentiating $\sin x$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1) \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

But now my sum starts at $n=1$ while the power series for $\cos x$ starts at $n=0$. Am I not missing the constant term "$1$" in my $\sin' x
\space \space $power series?

Comment: The sum in the sine starts at n=0, why the sum in the derivative of the sine starts at n=1?

Comment: I saw in a book that when you differentiate the sum starts at $1$ and not at $0$ but I guess that was because there was a constant term that became $0$ when differentiated which is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just missed that the $n=0$ term of the sine series is $x$, so it doesn't disappear when you differentiate it.

Comment: Oh, so I can only start my derivative sum at $1$ if I know that a constant term disappears?

Comment: Yes, point being that the first/zeroth term is not constant.

Answer (score 3):

loock at the firsts terms of the $\sin$ series:
$$
\sin x= x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots
$$
whan you derive you have:

$$
(\sin x)'= 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots
$$

so the series have allways a first term for $n=0$.

Comment: I misunderstood something in my textbook. The author started the sum at $n=1$ after differentiating but as I now realize and as the other answers have pointed out, that only works when the first term is constant and disappears after differentiating.